# Why do I get E_NOINTERFACE when creating an object that supports that interface?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, com

**Note:**

- Using [CoGetClassObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684007(VS.85).aspx), to create **multiple objects** through a class object for which there is a CLSID in the system registry
- Single threaded apartment

For **instance:**

```
hresult = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

IClassFactory *pIClassFactory;

hresult = CoGetClassObject (clsid, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, NULL, IID_IClassFactory, (LPVOID *)&pIClassFactory);


hresult = pIClassFactory->QueryInterface (IID_IUnknown, (LPVOID *)&pUnk);


hresult = pUnk->QueryInterface (__uuidof(IExample), (LPVOID *)&pISimClass);
```

**Note:**

- **E_NOINTERFACE** is returned

  - *ppvObject is set to **NULL**

**Question:**

- How can I confirm, that it is indeed registered - if this is the problem?

Comment: Please vote to close the post - as is no longer relevant. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are confusing the class object and the object itself. `CoGetClassObject` will give you a pointer to an object that implements `IClassFactory` and intended to create an instance of the object you are interested in. It is not an actual instance of that object.

In your example, you are getting an `IUnknown` pointer by calling `QueryInterface` on the `IClassFactory` pointer. This pointer still points to the instance of the class object, hence doing `QueryInterface` for the interface you are interested in results in an error. Instead you need to call [`IClassFactory::Createinstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682215(VS.85).aspx) to get the `IUnknown` pointer to the actual object and do the `QueryInterface` on that pointer.

Comment: Thanks - but now: "This connectable object does not support the outgoing interface specified"

Comment: If you post sample code what you are trying to do, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Also, take a look at CoCreateInstance function.